# Deploying large data on mongodb replicaset

Tags: mongodb

Can I deploy large database by copying its files (eg. testing database with files: testing.0,testing.1,testing.ns found on mongodb dbpath) from another server to the target servers (replica set) to avoid usage of communication bandwidth for replication (in case it is only deployed to the primary)? So basically I want to avoid the slow process of replication.

If journaling is enabled, what is the effect on the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, this is a perfectly valid way of solving having to do tedious and time consuming replication between members of a distanced or latenced network.

If journaling is enabled nothing really happens, copying via the file system goes around MongoDB.

Comment: Do I need to remove the secondary first on the replica set? If there is already an existing database what will happen to the data on the memory? Will the data on memory be updated? Or this can only be done by restarting the mongodb server, I have done it and it works on a non-replica server?

Comment: 1. I don't think so, your English is a bit vague but if I am reading right you can just spin up a new node with the copied data and it should be fine. 2. Always stop MongoDB on the member you are copying from and then to before copying/overwriting previous files else you could end up with inconsistencies like this. 3. No, stop MongoDB first, it will do a flush(). 4. You dont have to restart but I really would recommend you end MongoDB, copy the files over and then start again

Comment: The next problem is with the syncing on the primary. What do you suggest to initiate syncing/resyncing?

Comment: @Austin So long as the copy is new enough for the oplog to enable the new member catch up it should be fine

Comment: @Austin infact here is the doc which will explain other scenarios and methods: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/#replica-set-resync-by-copying